# wp-cli Enabling Maintainance Mode

Tags: wp-cli

During theme or plugin upgrades, maintenance mode is enabled and then disabled once complete.

Is it possible to manually enable / disable maintenance mode?

`Enabling Maintenance mode...
Downloading update from xxxx
Disabling Maintenance mode...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WP-CLI now has native commands for it.

```
# Activate Maintenance mode
$ wp maintenance-mode activate
# Deactivate Maintenance mode
$ wp maintenance-mode deactivate
```

See [`wp-cli/maintenance-mode-command`](https://github.com/wp-cli/maintenance-mode-command/blob/master/README.md) for more information.

Answer (score 9):

You can enable maintenance mode in WordPress by adding a `.maintenance` file to your root WordPress directory. It will need to include:

```
<?php
$upgrading = time();
```

With this file in place, your site will be in maintenance mode until you remove the file.

Comment: To add to that, WordPress looks at the timestamp of `$upgrading` and if it's more than 10 minutes old assumes the maintenance window has passed, and ignores the `.maintenance` file.

Comment: Which is not what OP asked for. They want to know how to do that using WP-CLI.

Comment: @leymannx There wasn't a way to enable / disable maintenance mode with WP-CLI at the time of my posting.

Answer (score 2):

I use a [plug-in](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-maintenance-mode/) for maintenance mode and always leave it "in" maintenance mode.

Practically you can then turn on/off the actual maintenance mode by turning on/off that plugi-in — which is easy through wp-cli:

```
# activate maintenance mode, flush caches and stuff
wp plugin activate ultimate-maintenance-mode
# do maintenance things
wp plugin deactivate ultimate-maintenance-mode
# flush caches again so the maintenance page does not show up
```

Comment: Great workaround! Although I can't believe there isn't a native feature in wp-cli that does that.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a native WordPress function that does this, so wp-cli has nothing to call on.

Comment: The Plugin is removed now.